# Return unique rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, group-by

I have a SQL Server table with 2 ID columns: `Employee_ID & Type_ID`

My table contains 4 rows:

```
Row 1 (Employee ID: 904, Type_ID: 3)
Row 2 (Employee ID: 904, Type_ID: 7)
Row 3 (Employee ID: 905, Type_ID: 7)
Row 4 (Employee ID: 905, Type_ID: 7)
```

I want to return all the type ID's that are available for all employees. So just `ID 7`.

So I want 1 row return with the ID of 7 as it is available for both employees (904 & 905)

If I run the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Type_ID, Count(Type_ID) as MyCount 
FROM 
    EmployeeType
WHERE 
    Employee_ID  IN (904, 905)  
GROUP BY 
    Type_ID
```

This returns me 2 rows

```
Row 1 (Type_ID: 3, MyCount: 1)
Row 2 (Type_ID: 7, MyCount: 3)
```

But I only what the record with the highest count (Type_ID 7). 
I tried adding:

```
HAVING MAX(Count(CostCentre_ID))
```

But this is obvuiouly illegal code.

How can I do this in my SQL?

Comment: "deleted" means the `row 2` has newer timestamp than `row 1` => it overwrites the old `type_ID` 3 with a new value - 7? or is there any `row_id` column? or how do you know the order of rows?

Comment: Just updated, sorry it should have read if row 1 was deleted.

Comment: @user1131657 I don't whats wrong with your Current Query.

Comment: there's no way to extract info from a deleted row... what is the expected and the actual output?

Comment: If row 1 was deleted then I would never get anything returned as the count isn't greater than one. I need to do this without using Count

Comment: I would just like ID 7 to be returned as both employees have that type

Comment: @user1131657 The query will worked, even if you **delete** the **row**

Comment: @user1131657 Even if the row with `3` in it is deleted you are grouping by `type_id` and your query will still work -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ef9/1

Comment: I've changed to question to try to explain it in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Barry's answer to get you the correct result even if there are "duplicate" rows like this:

```
declare @t table (
  employeeid int, typeid int, notes int
)
insert into @t
  select 904, 3, 0 union
  select 904, 5, 0 union
  select 904, 5, 1 union
  select 904, 7, 0 union
  select 905, 7, 0 union
  select 905, 7, 1 union
  select 908, 3, 0 union
  select 908, 5, 0 union
  select 908, 7, 0 union
  select 908, 9, 0 union
  select 908, 3, 0
```

Get all `typeid`s that are present for all `employeeid`s:

```
select typeid
from @t
group by typeid
having count(distinct employeeid) = (
  select count(distinct employeeid)
  from @t)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to find the `TypeId` is assigned to all `EmployeeId`.

```
Declare @t table
(
EmployeeId int,
TypeId int
)
Insert Into @t
Select 904, 3
Union 
Select 904, 5
Union 
Select 904, 7
Union 
Select 905, 5
Union 
Select 905, 7
Union 
Select 908, 3
Union 
Select 908, 7


Select Distinct a.TypeId
From @t a
Join 
(
    Select TypeId,
            COUNT(*) Over(Partition by TypeId)as [Occurs]
    From @t
)b on a.TypeId = b.TypeId

Where b.Occurs = (Select COUNT(Distinct(EmployeeId))
                From @t
                )
```

This returns `7` as that is the only `TypeId` assigned to all Employees.

Comment: `and a.EmployeeId in (904, 905)` - or what is `a` table good for?

Comment: @deathApril I have left the filtering out on `EmployeeId` as I am assuming that there may be many Employees so the query would calculate the `TypeId` assigned to all Employees regardless of how many there are.

Comment: so why not start with `b` table without `a`?

Comment: note this might give wrong results in special cases not covered by this question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12191/0

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
SELECT Type_ID, Occurance FROM 
(
SELECT Type_ID, Count(Employee_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_ID) AS Occurance
FROM EmployeeType
) T
WHERE T.Occurance > 2
```